# VimPlug unknown function plug#begin in NeoVim

Tags: vimrc, neovim, plugin-vim-plug

Recently I decided to switch from Vundle to VimPlug, and I noticed that after installing it...

- putting the `plug.vim` in my autoload directory `~/.vim/autoload/`
- and making sure that my vim and neovim was symbol linked so I didn't have to create a whole new set of directories just for neovim with this...

  ```
   ln -s ~/.vim ~/.config/nvim
   ln -s ~/.vimrc ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
  ```

I was still getting errors. It works perfectly in vim, but soon as I start up nvim I get these list of errors.

```
 Error detected while processing /home/username/.config/nvim/init.vim:
 line   26:
 E117: Unknown function: plug#begin
 line   28:
 E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
 line   29:
 E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
 line   30:
 E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
 line   31:
 E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
 line   32:
 E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
 line   34:
 E117: Unknown function: plug#end
```

This is the VimPlug section of my .vimrc

```
"[VIMPLUG]
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plug 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'

call plug#end()
"[VIMPLUG_END]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: It certainly looks like your `runtimepath` setting doesn't contain the right autoload folder (where `plug#...` functions are defined).

Comment: @VanLaser Well the autoload folder is within the `.vim` symbolic link so I really don't see why its not being able to see it when it works just fine in vanilla vim. Plus my `.vimrc` is really tiny so I really don't see anything else that what would be conflicting with it.

Comment: What's the output of running `:set runtimepath?` - check if your path is actually there or not.

Comment: @VanLaser `runtimepath=~/.config/nvim,/etc/xdg/nvim,~/.local/share/nvim/site,/usr/local/share/nvim/site,/usr/share/nvim/site,/usr/
share/nvim/runtime,/usr/share/nvim/site/after,/usr/local/share/nvim/site/after,~/.local/share/nvim/site/after,/etc/xdg/nv
im/after,~/.config/nvim/after`

Comment: @VanLaser Nevermind I figured it out. I posted a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason it doesn't seem to see VimPlug with the first symbolic link I had in my post. This is the only plugin I couldn't get to work in neovim with it.

So instead of making a symbolic link of `~/.vim` to `~/.config/nvim`. I decided to make a symbolic link of `~/.vim` to `~/.config/` (*note that I'm truncating the* `nvim` *part*).

So in terminal that will be `ln -s ~/.vim ~/.config/`

You'll see that it'll create a folder symbolic link called `.vim` rename it `nvim`

And then run this command `ln -s ~/.vimrc ~/.config/nvim/init.vim`

This will create a symbolic link of your `.vimrc` named `init.vim` inside that symbol link folder.

However, if you go to your vanilla `.vim` folder in your home directory you'll notice a `init.vim` there as well. **DON'T** delete this. Deleting this would result in the one you just created to get deleted, since putting a file in the folder your linking is basically putting it in that folder as well. This is the only way I got it to work without putting `plug.vim` in the nvim's system wide autoload folder.

Comment: Symlink seems to bork it for the `autoload` folder on OSX. `cp -r .vim/autoload .config/nvim/` fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is that you lack permissions for the folder ~/.vim or ~/.vim/autoload. The problem you are talking about can also occur in this situation.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might improve the answer by [edit]ing to explain how to correct the permissions or why this causes the problem